# Homotopy class of path and fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The question comes from Whitehead's book: Elements of Homotopy Theory, Chapter 6, Theorem 1.11(Page 263 below).

"
Let $B$ be a connected topological space. For each $b\in B$, choose an element $\xi(b)\in \pi_1(B;b_0,b)$, (where $b_0$ is a fixed point and $\pi_1(B;b_0,b)$ denotes the homotopy classes of the paths from $b$ to $b_0$) we may assume that $\xi(b_0)=1\in \pi_1(B;b_0)$."

**Q** I do not follow:

- What is the definition of $\xi(b_0)$? I guess it is the restriction of this homotopy class to the end point $b_0$.
- Why the author   assumes that $\xi(b_0)=1$?

Comment: I would say $\xi(b_0)$ is just some homotopy-class of loops based at $b_0$. However (without further context) I do not see any reason to assume that the fundamental group at $b_0$ is trivial, i.e. to assume that $\xi(b_0)=1$.

Comment: @NDewolf Thanks for your comments. You mean each homotopy class of the paths induces a (unique) homotopy-class of loops based at the endpoint of these paths. What is the definition?

Comment: I think the author tries to choose, for every $b\in B$, a homotopy class of paths from $b$ to $b_0$. In particular, the author wants to choose $1$, the class for the constant path, for $b_0$.

Comment: Well the definition of $\xi(b)$ is just some homotopy class of paths between $b_0$ and $b$. So if you take $b=b_0$ then this becomes a homotopy class of loops at $b_0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\xi(b)$ is a homotopy class of some path from $b$ to $b_0$ (it's not clear why would such path always exist, does the author actually assume that $B$ is **path** connected instead of just connected?).

When $b=b_0$ then there's a special path available: the constant path at $b_0$. And the author chooses it as $\xi(b_0)$. The "$1$" symbol typically corresponds to the identity element of the fundamental group, which in turn corresponds to the trivial constant loop.